# Search on site with phpmyadmin's DB

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search

How to create a search on my site with DB. It should search if even one word is congruence with the product's title and brand

```php
<?php 
    $host = "localhost";
    $db_name = "instrumentalka";
    $user = "root";
    $pass = "root";
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    $connection = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db_name);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
        die("Data Base connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error() . " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")");
    } else {
    # echo "Connection = success!\n" . mysqli_get_host_info($connection) . "<br />";
    }

    mysqli_query($connection, "SET NAMES utf8");

    // $query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM details");

    <form class="form-inline" method="POST" action="search.php">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" id="elastic" placeholder="Find" aria-label="Search" required>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit" name="search_btn">Find</button>
    </form>
?>
```

Comment: you need to use `FULL TEXT SEARCH`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this one (as I understood to your questions). First, add name to your input for example:

```
<input name="input"  class="form-control mr-sm-2" id="elastic" placeholder="Find" aria-label="Search" required>
```

and, add these lines after form

```
if(isset($_POST['input'])) {
        $text = $_POST['input'];
        $query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE clmn_name LIKE '%{$text}%'; ");
        $data = array();
        if(myqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
        }
        print_r($data);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Thanks for doing it without JS!